# how to remove time stamp from terminal in ubuntu

Tags: terminal, timestamp

I have a question on how to remove time stamps from terminal. I have to save space and was wondering on how to revert from -

```
  [7/29/2016 19:36] seed@ubuntu:
```

to

```
  seed@ubuntu:
```

I can't seem to find it. All I see is how to add time stamp but not how to remove it. If someone could help me, I would appreciate it.

EDIT: As suggested, I looked at ~/.bashrc,

I found this -

```
  PS1='[`date "+%x %H:%M"`] \u@\h:\w\$ '
  export PATH=.:$PATH
  alias ll='ls -l'
```

I tried to edit it by making the first line

```
  PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

but it didnt work. Not super familiar with this concept, so appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `.bashrc`

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Now execute it

```
$ . .bashrc
```

Only then will the changes take effect.

Note that the changes will take effect only for the current session. Which means if you open a new `Terminal` window, you will see the old `PS1`. You may restart your machine for the changes to be permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Not on Ubuntu, RHEL guy here, but that would normally be found in ~/.bashrc

Check there and see if there is anything obvious.  If you have any issues, paste your .bashrc file so I or someone else may take a look at it.

Comment: can you look at it now

Comment: For that change to take effect you are likely going to have to log out and back in.  Did you do that?